# seeding a foreign key in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a relationship between a user and its profile like this in Rails

```
User has_one :profile
Profile belongs_to :user
```

I understand that under normal circumstances Rails automatically creates the foreign key relationship between those two models.  However, when I am seeding the database with the information in the following way, with many Users created, and many Profiles created, then how do I ensure, for example,  that Joe's profile is linked with Joe's user account.

```
User.create!(email: "j@gmail.com", password: "blahblah", encryptedpass: "3838")
Profile.create!(first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Frank", address: "43 Flint Road", phone: "604 345 678", )

 User.create!(email: "anne@gmail.com", password: "blahblahblah", encryptedpass: "4567")
Profile.create!(first_name: "Anna", last_name: "Jones", address: "43 Boogy Road", phone: "604 345 678", )
```

**...imagine thousands of users and profiles being seeded in this way....**

Do i have to set a `user_id` foreign key on profile and, for the purposes of seeding it, do I just make up a foreign key id? Can rails generate it for me?  If for example, I made a foreign key on Joe's profile as `user_id: 1` how can I be sure that his instance of the user model will be "1" In other words, if I manually set his user_id foreign key, how can I make sure it'll match the id of the User model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `create_profile!` [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) (which is created by Rails when you declare `has_one :profile`

```
u = User.create!(email: "j@gmail.com", password: "blahblah", encryptedpass: "3838")
u.create_profile!(first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Frank", address: "43 Flint Road")
```